# Test where MouseLeave() leaves to

Tags: silverlight, event-handling, mouseevent

I've got a UserControl called myListItem that goes into ListBox'es. On mouse-over, it displays a pop-up window, and in that pop-up there's a scroll-view that the user might want to use to scroll the text in the view. I've made an event-handler that displays the pop-up when the mouse enters, but I'm struggeling a bit with when the mouse leaves. If the mouse leaves to the pop-up, the pop-up should stay up, but when the mouse leaves any other way, the pop-up should be disabled. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this? I'd think there would be a way looking a bit like this:

```
void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if(!e.Position.Intersects(itemPopUp.BoundingBox))
    itemPopUp.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this Popup XAML code:

```
<Popup x:Name="MyPopup">
    <Border Width="200" Height="200" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Pink"
            MouseLeave="Border_MouseLeave" MouseMove="Border_MouseMove" >

    </Border>
</Popup>
<TextBlock x:Name="MouseLeaveLoc" Text="N/A" />
```

and this in code behind (C#):

```
private void Border_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseLeaveLoc.Text = mouseLoc.ToString();
}

private Point mouseLoc;
private void Border_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseLoc = e.GetPosition(MyPopup);
    mouseLoc.X -= MyPopup.HorizontalOffset;
    mouseLoc.Y -= MyPopup.VerticalOffset;
}
```

mouseLoc contains the X,Y value relative to your popup content (here a Border control).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. :-) I hadn't thought about doing the subtraction you do in MouseMove(). If I understand you correctly, you suggest that I do the calculation myself, rather than using builtin functions?

Comment: Is there no hit-test associated with a Point? Something like this perhaps? 
   MyPopup.HitTest(e.GetPosition(null))